# Method addEagerConstraints does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have two models, User and Event. I made a pivot table, `invitations` between User and Event with a `status` column. In my Event model definition, I wrote this :

```
public function invited()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invitations', 'event_id', 'user_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->withPivot('status')
        ->orderByDesc('invitations.updated_at');
}

public function participants()
{
    $event = $this->with([
        'invited' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('invitations.status', InvitationStatus::ACCEPTED)->get();
        }
    ])->first();

    return $event->invited;
}
```

But when in my controller I do :

```
$event = Event::where('id', $id)->with(['owner', 'participants'])->first();
```

I have the following error :

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.
```

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you're trying to do this:

```
->with('participants')
```

Laravel expects to get a relationship instance. In other words, you can't use this method as a relation.

Comment: So I tried `$collection = collect($event); $collection->merge($event->participants);`, and I get `App\Event::participants must return a relationship instance`

Comment: @Wizix again, you shouldn't use this method as a relationship. When you use a method as a relationship, you must return `belongsTo()`, `hasMany()`, `belongsToMany()` etc.

Comment: @Wizix what worked? what was the final thing you wrote??

Answer (score -4):

`where` should come before `with`. This is what eloquent expects.

It should be like this:

```
$event = Event::with(['owner', 'participants'])->where('id', $id)->first();
```