# Eloquent - Merge results from two queries with aggregate/sum

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have tried for hours to get this but could do with some help. I have the following 2 queries which are summing columns on the same model but one of the sums requires a where condition.

In SQL I think this would be a relatively simple sub-select but I cannot get it working in eloquent.

```
public function receivedContents() : Collection
{
    return $this->stockMovements()
        ->with('product')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->where(function($query){
            $query->where('action', 'receive')->orWhere('action', 'void_receive');
        })
        ->get([DB::raw('SUM(received) as received_qty'), 'product_id']);
}

public function liveContents() : Collection
{
    return $this->stockMovements()
        ->with('product')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->get([DB::raw('SUM(received) + SUM(processed) as live_qty'), 'product_id']);
}
```

I am looking for a result with:

- product_id
- received_qty (a sum of received where action is received or void_received)
- live_qty (a simple sum or received + processed columns)

Ideally I want to keep this in an eloquent collection so I can still access the models relationships.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can simply use the `with`statement : `YourModel::with('receivedContents', 'liveContents')->get();`

Comment: Thanks, but these are not actually relationships, so this does not appear to work. I get the error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.`. Additionally, I need to run a `foreach ($model-> receivedContents() as $row)` where row contains `received_qty`, `live_qty` and `product_id`

Comment: because `with` should be the first statement like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129911/method-addeagerconstraints-does-not-exist)

Comment: Thanks for that. I removed the ->get() on each function to return and collection and that is now working, however it still provides the two separate collections and I need them to be combined.

Comment: You can use [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-merge) since you have product_id in both collection it would merge correctly.